# Meteor throwing "Exception from Deps recompute"

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, iron-router

Meteor throws an error "Exception from Deps recompute: username" when I return something not static inside the template's helpers.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
  this.route('dashboard');
})

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
  });

  Template.dashboard.helpers({
    username: function() {
      return Meteor.user().username;
    }
  });
}


<template  name="layout">
  <h1>Layout</h1>
  {{yield}}
</template>

<template name="home">
  {{#link route='dashboard'}}Dashboard{{/link}}
</template>

<template name="dashboard">
  {{#link route='home'}}Home{{/link}}
  {{username}}
</template>
```

The weird thing is, when visit the dashboard route by clicking the link in the home template, everything works fine. But when i type /dashboard in the url bar, I get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you manually navigate to a URL, it forces meteor to rerun the login process. So, while it's doing that, `Meteor.user()` will not return a valid object (and you therefore can't access `username`). You have two choices:

Add a guard to your code like:

```
Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().username;
```

or have your router show a "logging in" page while the login process is in progress.

Comment: Thank you :) And how would I ask my router to wait while the login process is running?

Comment: I have not yet migrated from meteor-router to iron-router so I can't tell you what I do for this. I'm actually a little surprised it isn't in the docs yet since this is such a common use case. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/286) issue for some suggestions.